# Gettting "Android App Not Installed. The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name" when installing new version

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I am trying to install a new signed release version of one of my app via file-manager present on my phone but I am getting this error message **"APP not installed The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name"**. I had already installed the previous version from google play Store both apks are signed from the same Keystore.

App Build Config from last version

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.1.9"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

App Build Config of new version

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 20
    versionName "1.2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I know after uninstalling the previous version I will be able to install a new version of the app but Will the users of my app will be able to update the app without uninstalling the previous version from play store? If not how can I avoid this situation?

---

**Update**

There are two copies of the apk at play store 1. Original One (Which you upload) 2.Derived One (Which Google play created by modifying your apk and this apk is distributed to everybody).

You can download both apks from here

Google Play Console -> Artifact Library -> Tap Download Button -> Now Google Play Will Ask you which apk you want to download.

So if you trying to update the app you downloaded from play store with the release signed one you created from the android studio you might get this error.but if you will upload the release signed apk to play store your users will be able to update the app without any error.

If You want to test thing database migration you can use the original apk.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked to see that you've fully removed the development version?   I've run into this sort of thing before and that was the cause.  If memory serves, that required a full uninstall of app, a reboot of the device and then install from store and install production build.   It might have even been that I had a test build under a different name, but same applicationId (I'd copied the project but only renamed some of the things) when playing with some proposed major UI changes.